# Finding solution for the intersection of a line and and arbitrary-order aspheric lens surface

Tags: math

**I apologize for any formatting mistakes, first time here.**

I'm currently working on program in Java as a personal project that simulates and allows for the design of a lens system with surfaces generally defined using the equations covered [here (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspheric_lens). In this case the "order" of the surface referring to the greatest a<sub>x</sub>r<sup>x</sup> value. Although possible, I'm pretty sure the order rarely is above 12.

Single solution:

[image: Single solution]

Multiple solutions:
[image: Multiple solutions]

The linked images show two possible cases for a complex aspherical lens defined using this particular equation:

[image: equation]

Assuming a "ray" comes from somewhere below the frame upwards as seen in the examples, how would I calculate the first point of collision between that ray and the lens surface? Specifically in three dimensions, as the examples above are only two dimensions as limited by Desmos. Being a lens, the resulting surface in three dimensions is possesses rotational symmetry where the 2D examples have reflection symmetry.

Edit removes unneeded sentence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not programming question.

Comment: I agree, there exists https://math.stackexchange.com for pure math questions

Comment: The description of the `math` tag says "Math involves the manipulation of numbers within a program. For general math questions, please ask on https://math.stackexchange.com/ ". Please read the description of a tag before deciding to use it. In this case, reading the description might have led you to realize that your question isn't on-topic on Stack Overflow.b